# How much the discrete subgroups of $\mathrm{O}(n)$ can be complicated?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, classifying-spaces

I have no intuition about the difficulty of classification of discrete subgroups of $\mathrm{O}(n)$  and I wanna to know about it.

> How much the discrete subgroups of $\mathrm{O}(n)$ can be complicated?

Comment: It depends: These groups are finite. Some people spend their entire life studying finite groups and their linear (equivalently, orthogonal) representations.

Comment: OMG.  So what we can do instead? (because we need that classification in geometry!!!)

Comment: Not much. If you assume, in addition, that the subgroup acts freely on the unit sphere, there are some interesting geometric/algebraic restrictions. Take a look in Joe Wolf's book "Spaces of constant curvature", which is a bit dated but still the best book available on the subject. https://www.ams.org/books/chel/372/chel372-endmatter.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any finite group can be embedded in some $O(n)$. If you believe finite groups are complicated, then that should give you some answer